# Bind the current item with original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of words:

```
let words = ['hello', 'world']
```

And I want to capitalize each one of them, what I'm doing is:

```js
let words = ['hello', 'world']

for (let word of words) {
    word = word.toUpperCase();
}
```

But each word is not binded to the iterable element, and the end result is the unchanged array.

Is there any way to bind each of the words to the array elements?

(Besides of the classic for(i=0; i

Comment: JavaScript strings are immutable, you cannot modify them. `word.toUpperCase()` returns an entirely new string. You need to replace the original string in the array with this new string. Better yet, replace the whole array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` for this:

```js
let words = ['hello', 'world'];

words = words.map(word => {
    return word.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(words);
```

Comment: Oh I really like this one, didn't thought of map. Thanks!